# Unable to achieve two way binding in Reactive-form Angular without ngmodel

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, two-way-binding

Below is what I have tried, when I hit enter after adding value in input field, I see just Gardening and Painting but but does not show the new values I enter.
Please help me understand what am I doing wrong here..

```
template file:
 <div formArrayName="hobbies">
     <h4>Your Hobbies</h4>
     <input type="text" class="form-group" (keyup.enter)="onAddHobby()">
     <ul class="list-group">
     <li *ngFor="let hobby of signUpForm.get('hobbies')['controls'];let i=index"
         class="list-group-item">{{hobby.value}}</li>
     </ul>
     </div>

typescript file:
ngOnIt{
'hobbies': new FormArray([new FormControl('Gardening'), new FormControl('Painting')])
}

onAddHobby(){
    const control= new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    (<FormArray>this.signUpForm.get('hobbies')).push(control);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in `onAddHobby()` method, you are pushing empty formcontrol in every time when you hit enter. Receive the value from the event and pass it to formControl something looks like,

In Html,

```
(keyup.enter)="onAddHobby($event.target.value)"
```

In Ts,

```
onAddHobby(value){
    const control= new FormControl(value, Validators.required);
    (<FormArray>this.signUpForm.get('hobbies')).push(control);
  }
```